# Rod on frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Suppose we have a uniform rod that initially is vertical. Find the minimum velocity at the point A (Va) such that the rod will fall and loss contact with the ground. Assume that the ground is frictionless, and the given values are its mass(m) and length (L) [image]

My problem is: Is it true when I say the point B is at rest (consider the time (t) approximately equals 0), after that it gonna leave the ground?

Comment: Does the rod have a diameter? In other words is it a cylinder? If yes then if Va is low enough it would tip on edge then rock back, not leaving ground.

Comment: Otherwise we could try thinking about how the force of gravity opposes the motion of B, but I'm not sure how exactly that would work

Comment: Uh, the object here is typically a chopstick. But if Va is enough to make it fall and loss contact with the ground,  can i say the point B is at rest in the begin ( t approximately =0)

Comment: The whole premise makes no sense to me. There are no horizontal forces shown so why would the rod fall over regardless of its velocity. Velocity is not a force

Comment: Actually, the velocity is the result of a particular force (of course, it no longer exerts on the object after very small amount of time). Imagine that the COM's trajectory looks similar to a projectile motion where there is only gravity force.

Comment: But you made no mention of an impulse. You need to make that clear.

Comment: I apologize for that

Comment: @Farcher that link is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the bottom of the rod is at rest as the top is put in motion, then point B will be an instantaneous axis of rotation.  For the rod to stay in contact with the surface, the critical condition is that the weight can supply the required centripetal acceleration for the center of mass: mg = m$({{v_A}/2)}^2)$/(L/2)  or ${V_A}^2$ = 2gL. For larger values of $v_A$, the rod will immediately pull away from the surface.  I have yet to consider smaller values of  $v_A$. My calculations indicate that if the stationary rod were struck by a horizontal linear impulse of m$v_A$/2, the center of mass would recoil with a velocity of $v_A$/2. For an angular impulse giving an initial $v_A$ at the top and 0 at the bottom the impulse would need to be applied at a distance of L/6 above the center of mass.

Comment: Could you explain the latter notion? Why should it be L/6?

Comment: Angular impulse (relative to CM.): [m($v_A$/2]d = Iω = [(1/12)m$L^2$]($v_A$/L). Solve for d.

Comment: well, what if the impulse was  applied at the point A? Could we have the same result, or the point B wouldnt stay at rest, may i ask?

Comment: With a horizontal impulse at the top: Ft = m$v_{cm}$ and Ft(L/2) = Iω If you want the same ($v_A$), then $(mv_{cm})(L/2) = [(1/12)mL^2]({v_A} – {v_{cm}})/(L/2)$.  Solve for $v_{cm}$.  The bottom will move.